# Using Netbeans 11 to write to a file using Java. Cannot get the end of file key sequence to work

Tags: java

Our assignment is to create and write to a text file using Java class Formatter. We are supposed to use a end-of-file key sequence to stop the input and write to the file. With the following code I am trying to use Z but nothing happens. The program keeps running. I am very perplexed because the Professor  cannot get it to work either 
Here is the code:

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.lang.SecurityException;
import java.util.Formatter;
import java.util.FormatterClosedException;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CreateTextFile {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //open clients.txt, output data to the filethen close the clienst.txt file
       try(Formatter output = new Formatter("clients.txt")){
       Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
       System.out.printf("%s%n%s%n?", "Enter account number, first name, last name and balance", "Enter end of file indicator to end input");

       while(input.hasNext()){
           try{
               //output new record to file; assumes valid intput
               output.format("%d %s %s %.2f", input.nextInt(), input.next(), input.next(), input.nextDouble());
           }
           catch(NoSuchElementException elementException){
               System.err.println("Invalid input. Please try again");
               input.nextLine();

           }
           System.out.print("?");
       }

               }
       catch(SecurityException | FileNotFoundException | FormatterClosedException e){
               e.printStackTrace();

       } 

    }
```

Comment: _"I am trying to use Z"_ Do you mean crtl-z? [while (scanner.hasNext()) loop not working twice? Java](//stackoverflow.com/a/19229115)

Comment: using <crtl>z and the file just keeps running.

Comment: Just tried on Windows 10 and it worked fine with ctrl-z.

Comment: Maybe this is helpful: https://coderanch.com/t/457941/java/input-File-indicator